# Installing Mollie payments API: unpermitted_parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mollie

I am installing the Mollie payments API. Unfortunately, I get an unpermitted parameters: _method, authenticity_token (in the log). Here I would expect that a new window is opened that connects with Mollie.

I call the API by:

```
    if @reservation

        mollie = Mollie::API::Client.new('test_gUejkz43UkdeCauC22J6UNqqVRdpwW')

        payment = mollie.payments.create(
            amount: 10.00,
            description: 'My first API payment',
            redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
        )
```

The reservation is made and the site does not give an active error, which makes me think the API is not called. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? I installed the gem, I use Rails 4 and use `require 'Mollie/API/Client'` on top of the controller.

Any suggestionis highly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Did you make it work in Rails?

Comment: yes got this working. Trick was to add redirect_to payment.payment_url

Comment: @ChrisRutte Could you please help with following [query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47427345/5963504)?